# Mono for Android - ExapandableListView

Tags: android, .net, mono, expandablelistview, xamarin.android

Does Mono for Android support ExpandableListView?
If so, is there an example of this where the selected item is available as a CLR type?

Clarification:

*I have looked into implementing this, yet we have faced issues in extending the BaseExpandableListAdapter due to the Java.Lang.Object being the return type of the method signatures.*

Comment: I don't understand "Java.Lang.Object being part of the numerous signatures."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is exposed as [Android.Widget.ExpandableListView](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.ExpandableListView)

You can use the [SelectedId](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.ExpandableListView.SelectedId) and [SelectedPosition](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.ExpandableListView.SelectedPosition) properties on the list's adapter ([IExpandableListAdapter](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.IExpandableListAdapter)) to get at the underlying item that is selected.

Comment: Can you provide an example to back up your answer?